# how do i add the latest folder made in a pen drive to my batch file command

Tags: batch-file, command-line

eg my latest folder made is 20150106 so i want to use it as an existing file's name as cd c:/20150106

i want cd c:/%latest_folder_name%
i have many folders made **ALMOST** daily as 20150103 , 20150104 as a backup so now the task is to copy the latest folder to d drive from the inserted pen drive. please don't talk any thing of date command bcoz its not the date command that matters i just want the latest folder's name.

please help

my job is of great importance i tell u
i have already tried posting on yahoo answers
plzzz help me

i just want the latest folder's name extracted automatically

Comment: the latest folder with the format "YYYYMMDD" or the "really" latest folder?

Comment: YYYYMMDD format onlly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get all folders starting with "20" (`/ad`= Attribute Directory) (`/b` print name only)

```
dir /ad /b 20*
```

get them sorted by name:

```
dir /ad /b 20* |sort
```

or
    dir /ad /b /on 20*

get the latest of it (by name, not by "modified date")

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /ad /b /on 20*') do set latest=%%i
```

If you want the last modified folder, use (

```
dir /ad /b /o-d /tw
```

(for explanation of the parameters see `dir /?`)